# How do I get an object's info in JavaScript

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata

I tried following the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) for `getObjectInfo`, but haven't been able to retrieve anything. Starting with their sample code, I have this JavaScript in my experiment component:

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class RecordFormWithRecordType extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('objectInfo: ', this.objectInfo);
    }
}
```

The console *does* report a value for `this.objectInfo`, but it's just the `data` and `error` keys with `undefined`, no actual object info.

This sounds like a very useful function to build dynamic components using the metadata, but how do I use it to actually *get* metadata?

Comment: The wire calls are async so you will need to wait and process the results when available. Please review if this helps. https://medium.com/@varma6228/getobjectinfo-in-lwc-1ffe490ea396

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info is in the `data` object. The [Wire Service docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) have more information about understanding the usage of the `@wire` annotation in general. The section "Decorate a Function with @wire" shows an example for handling callbacks.

```js
// wireFunction.js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class WireFunction extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track record;
    @track error;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Name'] })
    wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }
    get name() {
        return this.record.fields.Name.value;
    }
}
```